# Can we automatically generate different test scenarios for a given API end point ? Manually doing it requires effort, time and hence delays

Tags: rest, automated-tests, web-api-testing

No matter what project I am on, I am constantly doing the same process of writing API tests. This work seems redundant and I think it can be automated.

My question: has anybody out there automated the generation of different possible test scenarios for a given API endpoint? What tool did you use?

Please let me know. I am writing API tests (for different test scenarios) at the end of sprint for what feels like the millionth time.

Thanks!

Comment: This question needs to be more specific. Just to be clear, you want to automate manual test cases, or do you want to automate the process of adding new automated test cases? Also, maybe this question would fit more on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/, since it's related to testing process and strategy.

Comment: I meant automatically generate test scenarios. Suppose I have an API end point, now I want to generate different scenarios possible(which requires manual effort of thinking all scenarios and writing them)

Comment: If you'll talking about generation manual test scenarios, you could generate test scenarios test are common to all endpoints e.g. test request payload with all data types, and verify the generic response, test with expected data types(you can add random values here), expected/unexpected headers etc. But there are also endpoint specific test scenarios which you need to find on your own. You can do this programmatically in any language you want. In the upcoming future (if it's not already), we could integrate ML algorithms that could generate test scenarios.